# Regionalisms: ideally we need a map widget! — Régionalismes : dans l'idéal il nous faudrait un map widget !

Tags: discussion

We have a bunch of questions about regionalisms and when it comes to draw boundaries between associated geographic areas, unfortunately, we lack a proper way to combine everyone's knowledge. Currently, odds are it will turn into debacle.

What if question and answers were to reference existing usages in a codified manner. Each of these usages would then be represented as a color. A map with French-speaking countries is displayed (for example, under the question post). And vote-enabled users can color each of the regions they know with the usages they know of!

Ok, sure, deploying this idea is delicate matter. Basically, it means that someone or a group of motivated people has to develop a webapp that will parse answers, display a map, allow authenticated users to color parts of the map, and that StackExchange accepts¹ to run the app on questions tagged “geographic-area”.

It's just an idea… but the only one I can come with that would bring something out of those particular questions.

What do you think? Up to it?

—
<sup>1. Assuming the SE API does permit issue of authenticated requests, we could perhaps build this up as an external service.</sup>

---

Nous avons « moultes » questions à propos des régionalismes et lorsqu'il s'agit d'estimer une étendue géographique, malheureusement aucun moyen de combiner les connaissances de chacun de façon concise. C'est presque à coup sûr la débâcle.

Dans l'idéal ce serait bien que la question et les réponses puissent mentionner les différents usages en vigueur d'une façon codifiée. À chacun de ces usages serait associé une couleur. On aurait alors une carte des pays francophones affichée (par exemple, en dessous de la question) sur laquelle les utilisateurs qui ont le droit de vote pourraient colorer chacune des régions qu'ils connaissent avec l'usage qui correspond !

Ok, pour mettre en place cette idée ça va bien sûr être un poil compliqué. En gros, il faudrait qu'un ou quelques motivés codent l'appli web qui parse les réponses, affiche la carte et permette aux gens authentifiés de colorier, et que StackExchange accepte¹ de faire tourner l'appli sur les questions tagguées «  étendue-géographique ».

Juste une idée. Mais je ne vois aucune autre façon de faire fonctionner les questions qui s’intéressent aux portées géographiques correctement.

Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ? Et surtout, qui est motivé ? :-)

—
<sup>1. Je ne sais si l'API de SE permet d'envoyer des requêtes authentifiées, dans ce cas on peut éventuellement se débrouiller avec un service externe.</sup>

Comment: I've tried the tag "étendue-géographique" http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etendue-geographique but nothing goes. Where is this "bunch of questions about regionalisms" ?

Comment: @Istao: ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regionalismes.

Answer (score 2):

C'est sûr que ça serait bien, mais ça me paraît compliqué pour un domaine d'utilisation somme tout limité.

---

Sure, it would be nice, but it looks pretty complicated to me for a rather limited use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to use tags like [quebec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quebec) or [suisse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suisse) and to document the wiki of this tag. Perhaps it's possible to put in wiki tag a map ?

Comment: You can put images in answers and tag wikis, but I don't think this is related to this question. Tags apply to questions, the idea here is more to tag answers.